# What is the best way to pass this variable from the component to reposotory.js?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I want to pass variable from component vue.js to js file. I use repository pattern in my app. I have two identical repositories but they have different resources. What is the best way to pass this variable from the component to reposotory.js

For example

*FirstRepository.js*

```
import Repository from "@/plugins/axios";

const resource = "/first";
export default {
  getList(params) {
    return Repository.get(`${resource}/`, { params });
  },
```

*SecondRepository.js*

```
import Repository from "@/plugins/axios";

const resource = "/second";
export default {
  getList(params) {
    return Repository.get(`${resource}/`, { params });
  },
```

*index.vue*

```
....
import FirstRepository from "@/api/FirstRepository.js";
...
methods: {
    async loadItems() {
      const { data } = await FirstRepository.getList(params);
    },
}
```

I think I need to use vuex.Please tell me how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I used factory pattern

CommonRepository.js

```
import Repository from "@/plugins/axios";

export const useRepository = (resource) => {
  const getList = (params) => {
    return Repository.get(`${resource}/`, { params });
  };
...
return { getList, ... };
}
```

index.vue

```
....
import { useRepository } from "@/api/CommonRepository";
const repository = useRepository("/first");
...
methods: {
    async loadItems() {
      const { data } = await repository.getList(params);
    },
}
```